# Why an adversary can guess a secret while we have provided differential privacy?

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

Let's consider a scenario with $k$-*secrets*, each associated with a user. Every user aims to obscure their respective secret using a $d$-*privacy* method.

We say a user uses $d$-*privacy* within a radius $r$ if the distributions of observations or obfuscated secrets from any two locations within a distance of at most $r$ are "similar," with the level of similarity determined by $d$.

Assume that our $d$-*privacy* mechanism works fine. Let's now introduce an adversary who is aware of the initial $k$ secret values. The issue arises when the adversary can probabilistically link any obfuscated secret to one of the original secrets with a probability of at least $1/k$. This situation is perplexing because differential privacy is expected to ensure privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differential privacy is only concerned with limiting the additional knowledge an adversary gains by observing a dataset /in addition/ to what they already had before. It can, naturally, not "get rid of" any a-priori knowledge an adversary may have had.

Consider the fictional illness Cluckitis of which it is known that 10% of muppets are affected. For any muppet you encounter you already know that there's a 10% chance they'll behave like a chicken.

If I publish a dataset analysing the relation between fur colour and Cluckitis, then me using a mechanism of differential privacy only limits the additional knowledge you gain from that dataset, in addition to what you already knew before.

Comment: I appreciate your concise response. Can you elaborate on a strategy to prevent the adversary with prior knowledge, in my scenario, from successfully guessing a secret with a significant likelihood?